# How do I stop OBS from contrasting my mouse pointer?

Tags: software, obs

I just started transitioning from Xbox Game Bar which I previously used for recordings to OBS, and I don't know why, but the game I'm playing records the mouse in a very different way. The first image is how the recording looked to me and Xbox Game Bar, and the second is what OBS showed. Obviously, OBS is trying to contrast the mouse to the background, but I don't want that. How would I turn mouse contrast off?

[image: pointer type 1]
[image: pointer type 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script looks as though it would allow you to add a "skin" to your mouse cursor, which would allow you to make the mouse cursor look like whatever you wanted:

https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-studio-mouse-cursor-skin.1010/

Comment: I'm confused - how would I download all of this?